# Docker install old chromium version

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm creating a Docker image installing chromium and chromium-driver, but everytime i run the python script, it crash due to render problem.
The error return this: Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114
So i tried to install all this package directly on raspberry and not in a container, and the script runs fine with chromium and chromium-driver version: 106.0.5249.119

Why docker file install old version?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.2

RUN apt-get update

# install chromium
RUN apt-get install -y chromium

# install chromium-driver
RUN apt-get install chromium-driver

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . /data
WORKDIR /data
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:0

# custom env vars
ENV DOCKER_IMAGE=true
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/data/****.py", line 799, in main_function
    browser = browserSetup(True, PC_USER_AGENT)
  File "/data/****.py", line 42, in browserSetup
    chrome_browser_obj = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.114)
```

Browser creation python script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
prGreen("[DOCKER] Setting flags for Docker")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("user-agent=" + user_agent)
options.add_argument('lang=' + LANG.split("-")[0])
if headless_mode :
    options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
chrome_browser_obj = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
return chrome_browser_obj
```

Comment: Please provide the full error with traceback

Comment: Python error added!

Comment: Also can you please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your python script?

Comment: Yes, i added the section where i create the browser session and the error occures

Comment: I am not an expert in raspberry-pi. But with what you have posted I have a feeling this may be due to a port mapping issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Looking at your code the versions of chromium and chromedriver seem to match, the difference between docker and a raspberry are based on the different OS (debian has older packages). I tried your code and it returned no errors. I can share my simplified code as an answer if you think it can be helpful. What value does `headless_mode` have? Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes Matteo, if you can share it with, it'll be helpfull.

Comment: The headless_mode is a boolean variable given by the function call and is used for headless browser mode (with a browser window or without a window all in background)